# How to solve this specific combinatorial optimization task?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

I have problems with my combinatorial optimization task:

Different teams of the same company may have employees in different cities. If employees have the same position, we can change their teams (we cannot change the city of an employee). And the goal is to distribute employees to teams in such a way as to maximize the number of teams that have employees sitting together in the same city.

Example: Team A consists of three people: two designers and one manager. The designers are in London and the manager is in Manchester. Team B consists of 4 employees: two managers and two Java developers. One of the managers is in London, all the rest are in Liverpool. In this case, it would be optimal to move one manager who is in London to team A, and a manager from Manchester to team B.

So, data we have: employee, it's team, it's position, it's city:

```
employee_id  team     position     city
11            A       Manager     London
12            A       Designer    London
.......................................
```

There are a huge number of such teams and cities, and I want to find the most optimal solution. It seems to me that this is similar to the knapsack problem, but more difficult. What algorithm could be used here? I have no idea(

Comment: I have not thoroughly thought about it, but you could see if it can be formulated as a network flow optimization

Comment: @VanBaffo could i use Hungarian algorithm for this task?

Comment: It seems indeed related